# recording screen to video libgdx android

Tags: android, screen, record, libgdx

I have to record the screen within the libgdx application and share the video to youtube within the same application. I compiled the ffmpeg project to obtain the binary file FFMPEG. I took a list of screenshots within the app and i need to convert them to video. Is FFMPEG the easiest way to convert the pictures + sound to movie ?
I added to assert folder the FFMPEG file. Now i tried to execute it with:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("chmod 700 ffmpeg");
    rt.exec("ffmpeg");
```

It cannot be done because of the path, it seems to be wrong.(standard assertmanager cannot be used inside libgdx for the moment)
I tried to copy the file from assert folder to other location like this:

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("ffmpeg");
FileHandle destHandle = Gdx.files.external("/data/data/com.me.putingame.VideoProcessor/ffmpeg");
handle.copyTo(destHandle);
```

but because is an external file i dont know the path to execute the ffmpeg for encoding. What path sould i use?

How can i manage to execute ffmped inside of unrooted devices using libgdx? Some lines of code will be usefull

Is this the best way in recording video within android?

Regards,
Marius

Comment: You've got too many diverse questions in one post.  I think the external-path answer answers your questions, but the title and most of the body aren't really relevant.  Can you narrow this question down?

Comment: I found myself the answer to the upper issue. The project from link below do ffmpeg conversion from png to video within android app. The only issue that remains is recording of the sound. https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the full path of `destHandle` I think this should work:

```
 String fullpath = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath() + "/" + destHandle.path();
```

See http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Files.html#getExternalStoragePath()